# Convert a 16 bit compressed kinect depth image to something usable?

Tags: slam, navigation, opencv, openni

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I don't know why, but I have a 16 bit Kinect depth image recorded in my bag file.
And now I want to use rgbd_slam for processing.

Is there a solution to get this working, because the normal bitrate is 32Bit depth, isn't it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67674/convert-a-16-bit-compressed-kinect-depth-image-to-something-usable?/) by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) on ROS Answers with karma: 496 on 2013-07-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What other data is in your bagfile, please post the output of `rosbag info <yourbagfile>`. If you have a cloud, set the topic for the depth image in rgbdslam's parameters to "" (empty string). Otherwise, try setting the "depth_scaling" parameter to 0.001 (I'm guessing that the 16bit thing contains millimeters).

I am unsure what you mean by "compressed" in the title? That the bagfile is compressed? That wouldn't have any impact (except the cpu performance required to decompress).

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2013-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [madmax](https://answers.ros.org/users/1492/madmax/) on 2013-07-22**:
Well, you answered my [other question](http://answers.ros.org/question/64666/openni-depth-image-problem/) regarding the strange depth image in my bag file.  The normal image_transport decompressing does not work for me, so I looked how rqt_gui did the thumbnail view, and took this approach. The just make a python image out of it and I convert it back to a ros image. So now I have this image, but then RGBD throws an opencv error that says it can't convert to bayer_grbg8 or so. Don't know the error exactly, as I am not at university right now...